# Save archived Excel files with the same name to Github as one file

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I have archived 10 versions of the same excel file on my computer. I was basically manually filling out cells in Excel and wanted to save my progress in between for safekeeping. All files are formatted like this "YYMMDD SLR Adversity - Analysis.xlsx", where YYMMDD represents the date when I archived the Excel file. I would now like to archive all Excel files on Github, but I want to make sure that Github recognizes these as the same file called "Name". How can I add these excel files to Github as multiple versions of the same file?

I have tried using:

```
for file in *.xlsx
do
    new_file=$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/([0-9]{6}).*SLR Adversity - Analysis.xlsx/SLR Adversity - Analysis.xlsx')
    mv "$file" "$new_file"
    git add "$new_file"
    git commit --author-date="$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*/20\3-\2-\1/')  -m "$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/([0-9]{6}).*Adversity - Analysis.xlsx/\1/')"
done
```

but there seems to be mistake because the code is not completed. However I thought that done finishes the loop.

Comment: I'd do this: loop over all files sorted by name; on every loop do `mv "YYMMDD Name.xlsx" Name.xlsx && git add Name.xlsx && git commit --author-date=YY-MM-DD -m "YY-MM-DD"` Of course `YYMMDD` and `YY-MM-DD` here are variables from the file name, not literals.

Comment: Could you explain what this code does? :)

Comment: `mv` rename the file to the fixed name, `git add && git commit` commit the file; option `--author-date` sets the date that will be visible in `git log`; `-m` sets commit message.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try it out later today and get back to you.

Comment: Excel files have built-in versioning. Instead of saving 10 different copies of the file, enable versioning and save a new version when you need to. `git` doesn't understand the contents of an `xlsx` file and can't tell you what changed, show you the history of actual changes or roll back to specific versions. It can only replace the entire binary file